# How do I get the number of jobs in a rq queue?

Tags: python, resque

I've using [rq](http://python-rq.org/) and RedisToGo. How do I get the number of jobs in the queue? I can't find it in the documentation? (In Python)

When I try:

```
print "Before: ", len(q.jobs)
result = q.enqueue(worker.A)
result = q.enqueue(worker.B)
print "After: ", len(q.jobs)
```

It just gives 0 both times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For RQ, you should be able to just get the `len` of the jobs in a queue:

```
from rq import Queue

queue = Queue()
len(queue)
```

Comment: Looks like there is a `q.count` property as well. https://github.com/nvie/rq/blob/master/rq/queue.py#L85-L88

Comment: `q.count` is much faster than `len(queue.jobs)`

Comment: The source code of `len(q)` is literally `def __len__(self): return self.count`, so no `len(q.jobs)` is required.